# Browser loads both shorthand CSS with px, and specific css with rem on same property?

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-size

I've began working on a new site using REM units with PX fallbacks. Now, I have a question that may be silly, but I can't find anything specifically mentioning it so I'll just go ahead and ask here.

Using property shorthands and specific properties seems to both <strike>load</strike> take effect in <strike>the browser</strike> Chrome.

```
body{ font:16px/23px sans-serif;
      font-size:1rem;
      line-height:1.438; }
```

whereas using both shorthand or both specific properties cancels one or the other out (e.g. uses primary or fallback, not both)

```
body{ font-family:sans-serif;
      font-size:16px; font-size:1rem;
      line-height:23px; line-height:1.438; }
```

or

```
body{ font:16px/23px sans-serif;
      font:1rem/1.438 sans-serif; }
```

Now which is exactly best practice here? All examples validate.
Is there a reason why the shorthands AND specific properties both load in <strike>the browser</strike> Chrome even though they're targeting the same properties? Are they *actually* both loading?
Does this have any adverse effects to how the browser/device is rendering the styles?

<strike>I've only looked into this via Chrome and</strike> I haven't been able to discern any differences through testing. But, You can see how it would be a little bulky if you HAD to use two iterations of the same code for all elements using rem's.

**UPDATE:**
Tested only in latest versions of all browsers below, all tests pertain to the first code snippet

In Firefox this doesn't seem to be an issue, it just replaces the font-size/line-height in the shorthand code with the rem sizing.
In IE, safari, & Opera it takes the shortcode and separates it into specific properties, but still loads the rem units ignoring the px units.

It seems to be specific to Chrome, at least in modern versions. So the question now, how to figure out how Chrome is handling it? The image, displayed at the bottom of this post, may explain a little more. See how BOTH font properties are loaded and neither are ignored or take precedence?

**UPDATE#2:**
When using margins, Chrome acts properly. I'll use the following "off the wall" example to demonstrate:

```
margin:16px 0 19px 0;
margin-top:1rem;
margin-bottom:1.188rem;
```

reads in chrome as:

```
margin:1em 0 1.188rem 0;
```

[image: screenshot of google "inspect element" on body]
<sub>(source: [leftdeaf.com](http://leftdeaf.com/chromefont-size.jpg))</sub>

Comment: What do you mean when you say "load"? Does it mean "take effect"? Firefox seems to be acting correctly in this case, since this seems to be a simple matter of cascading. (Why it says `line-height: 1.438` in Chrome's Web Inspector and not `line-height: 1.438rem` as stated in your code is beyond me.)

Comment: @BoltClock, Yes I meant take effect, or be used as primary (rem) or fallback to secondary (px). One should override the other. I just wanted to amend ONLY the font size in the shorthand `font:500 16px/23px sans-serif;` with specific property such as `font-size:1em;` A similar example would be using a shorthand `margin:0 16px 0 0;` and only the right margin with `margin-right:1rem;`. But as Xarcell mentioned, I'll just have to re-write it identically, one as px and one as rem, like so: `margin:0 16px 0 0; margin:0 1rem 0 0;` or `margin-right:16px; margin-right:1rem;` repetitive, but works.

Comment: Also, line-height not showing "rem" on the end was because I update that stylesheet, prior to the screenshot, after reading http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/. I've updated it here as well now, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of wasted time and confusion... It actually does render correctly in Google Chrome. **feeling silly now**... I overlooked the drop-down arrow to the sub-properties in the Chrome Tools. Image displays what I overlooked. Example shows multiple examples of shorthand properties and specific properties, more importantly it shows the `font` property working, it wasn't <strike>crossed out</strike> but it was still being overridden. Not sure why it doesn't comply with the <strike>strike through</strike> like everything else, probably due to the font-weight, variant, style properties remaining unchanged. But it works.

[image: Doh!]

Answer (score 1):

This two resources will answer all of your questions:

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

http://blog.typekit.com/2011/11/09/type-study-sizing-the-legible-letter/

With line-height, use the unit, but not the value:

body { 
font:16px/23px sans-serif;
font: 1rem sans-serif;
line-height:1.438; 
}

or

body { 
font-size:16px/23px;
font-size: 1rem;
font-family: sans-serif;
line-height:1.438; 
}

You can't use FONT and FONT-SIZE, just use one or the other. Otherwise the browser will attempt to use both.

Comment: Love the typekit link, as it lead me to this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/ which is a great article and explains the unitless line-height well. However, that isn't what I was speaking on. 

In the image link, you'll see, chrome is loading both the px and rem elements in unison: http://leftdeaf.com/chromefont-size.jpg both seem to be applied on top of each other. I'm aware of how rem/px works (although the unitless line-height was new so thanks for that).

Comment: put PX before REM. Browsers always use the last one, and if it doesn't understand the last one, it ignores it, leaving you with the first one. Also, the reason it is using both, is because you area using FONT and FONT-SIZE. You need to pick one or the other, not both...

Comment: understood, looked as if it were working in all but chrome, it seemed to be ignoring the px in light of the em even with the font-size/font differences in all other browsers, but I guess I'll just have to move forward with a more bulky, but properly working, implementation. Thanks

Comment: "You can't use FONT and FONT-SIZE, just use one or the other. Otherwise the browser will attempt to use both." You *can* use them both together. Whether you use a shorthand and/or its component properties should not affect cascading in unexpected ways - whatever is happening seems to be a browser bug more than anything.

Comment: @BoltClock, That's what I originally thought, but wasn't sure if it was poor use or not, second guessed it. Hence why I came here for further review.

Comment: @Xarcell you made a small typo in your 2nd example `font-size:16px/23px;` can't have the line-height on `font-size` property, only validates on shorthand `font` property so you'll need to edit that by way of adding `sans-serif` and removing the `size`

Comment: @BoltClock, what I said was you have to use one or the other, otherwise the browser will attempt to use BOTH. You just quoted what I said, then tell me I'm wrong. WTF? Using Both will cause in-consistencies, especially with larger sizes, so you need to use one or the other. Test it yourself, and read again the quote on made on me. Now I'm not the accepted answer because of a mistake you made...

Comment: @Xarcell You're not the accepted answer anymore due to the fact that your answer wasn't the most accurate response any longer. I'm not saying it was a bad response. I'm saying it isn't the most accurate any longer.